# DAX - Blank values produced in my pivot when combining CALCULATE and PREVIOUS MONTH

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have created a data table and marked it as a date table. I have the following measures:

HispPop = SUM([Total_Population_Hispanic_Latino])

2021HispPop = CALCULATE([HispPop],PREVIOUSYEAR('Calendar'[Date]))

[image: Pivot Table with blanks]

[image: Snippet of data in PowerPivot window]

Comment: As you can see from the pivot table snippet, the 2021HispPop is all blanks rather than populating with each city's 2021 HispPop value

Comment: Have you added a relationship between your calendar and the other table?

Comment: yes, i have added a relationship

Comment: Can you share your excel file or the model ?

Comment: I do not know how to share the file

Comment: Here is some sample data:

Date ZipCode Total_Population Total_Population_Hispanic_Latino
1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM 32008 5920 956
1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM 32003 29505 2888
1/1/2022 12:00:00 AM 32008 6338 826
1/1/2022 12:00:00 AM 32003 29810 3066